# Admob android issue 'No fill from any mediation ad networks' with Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I have been using Admob many years now in my Android Apps.
Recently I tried to update one of my Apps and I after that I keep getting "No fill from any mediation ad networks.". I havent chaged the admob ads java code or anything else. Then I tried various updates of Google Services and in the end I also updated from Eclipse to Android Studio 2.2.2. Everything else works perfectly except this. I get the same error no-mater what I do. I tried it on 2 android devices one Samsung Tablet and one Galaxy S7. Same result.
I attach the log. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```html
11-27 16:48:33.710: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
11-27 16:48:33.718: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 481K, 49% free 4353K/8392K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 21ms
11-27 16:48:33.828: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-27 16:48:33.828: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1022K, 49% free 4354K/8392K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 25ms
11-27 16:48:33.828: D/dalvikvm(4984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
11-27 16:48:33.976: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1531K, 49% free 4356K/8392K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 22ms
11-27 16:48:33.976: D/dalvikvm(4984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
11-27 16:48:33.992: E/Watchdog(484): !@Sync 10
11-27 16:48:34.062: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 478K, 49% free 4351K/8392K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 26ms
11-27 16:48:34.156: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
11-27 16:48:34.156: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 488K, 49% free 4351K/8392K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 29ms
11-27 16:48:34.320: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-27 16:48:34.320: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 982K, 49% free 4362K/8392K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 26ms
11-27 16:48:34.492: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:35.632: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1531K, 48% free 4364K/8392K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 29ms
11-27 16:48:35.664: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:35.734: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 447K, 49% free 4354K/8392K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 23ms
11-27 16:48:36.335: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:36.351: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 442K, 49% free 4352K/8392K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 31ms
11-27 16:48:36.437: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 475K, 48% free 4365K/8392K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 27ms
11-27 16:48:36.539: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
11-27 16:48:36.539: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 49% free 4352K/8392K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
11-27 16:48:36.640: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-27 16:48:36.640: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 669K, 49% free 4351K/8392K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
11-27 16:48:36.726: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.talk (pid 4514) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:36.726: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 4444) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:36.742: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.osp.app.signin (pid 4592) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:36.835: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:37.335: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:37.781: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 963K, 42% free 4906K/8392K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 37ms
11-27 16:48:38.015: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:38.335: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:38.898: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.apps.books (pid 4466) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:38.906: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.sec.spp.push:RemoteNotiProcess (pid 4853) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:38.929: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.apps.docs (pid 4383) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:38.968: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1065K, 49% free 4350K/8392K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
11-27 16:48:38.968: D/dalvikvm(4984): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
11-27 16:48:38.992: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 49% free 4350K/8392K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
11-27 16:48:38.992: I/dalvikvm-heap(4984): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.448MB for 578992-byte allocation
11-27 16:48:39.007: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
11-27 16:48:39.015: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 42% free 4916K/8392K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-27 16:48:39.039: E/dalvikvm(4984): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
11-27 16:48:39.039: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 42% free 4916K/8392K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 28ms
11-27 16:48:39.195: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.1 9.8
11-27 16:48:39.335: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:40.195: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.apps.plus (pid 3322) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:40.203: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.videos (pid 4195) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:40.203: I/ActivityManager(484): Process com.google.android.gm (pid 4219) (adj 15) has died.
11-27 16:48:40.343: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:40.421: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.1 9.8
11-27 16:48:41.101: I/Monitor(484): SIOP:: Current AP = 0, CP = 0
11-27 16:48:41.343: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:41.601: D/SensorService(484):   0.4 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:42.343: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:42.773: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:43.664: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.os.Bundle.putBinder, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ac.a
11-27 16:48:43.664: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2727: Landroid/os/Bundle;.putBinder (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V
11-27 16:48:43.664: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
11-27 16:48:43.710: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
11-27 16:48:43.710: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2946: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
11-27 16:48:43.710: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
11-27 16:48:43.781: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method hyx.a
11-27 16:48:43.781: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2339: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-27 16:48:43.781: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
11-27 16:48:43.789: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method hyx.p
11-27 16:48:43.789: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2918: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
11-27 16:48:43.789: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
11-27 16:48:43.945: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.1 9.8
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 784 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 785 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 784 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 783 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: I/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0310 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.a
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: I/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0310 at 0x17 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
11-27 16:48:44.007: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
11-27 16:48:44.007: I/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x030f at 0x26 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/internal/NativeLibUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
11-27 16:48:44.085: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
11-27 16:48:44.085: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2232: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
11-27 16:48:44.085: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
11-27 16:48:44.085: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.ModuleContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
11-27 16:48:44.085: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2233: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
11-27 16:48:44.085: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
11-27 16:48:44.093: D/DynamitePackage(4984): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
11-27 16:48:44.093: D/DynamitePackage(4984): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
11-27 16:48:44.148: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.os.Bundle.putBinder, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ac.a
11-27 16:48:44.148: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2420: Landroid/os/Bundle;.putBinder (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/IBinder;)V
11-27 16:48:44.148: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
11-27 16:48:44.195: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
11-27 16:48:44.195: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static method 2563: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
11-27 16:48:44.195: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0080
11-27 16:48:44.203: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method zz.a
11-27 16:48:44.203: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2120: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-27 16:48:44.203: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c
11-27 16:48:44.210: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method zz.a
11-27 16:48:44.210: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2553: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
11-27 16:48:44.210: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0065
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128): Failed to load module version: 
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ConfigurationManager.getModuleVersion(:com.google.android.gms:564)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.ModuleProvider.query(:com.google.android.gms:1103)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
11-27 16:48:44.281: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-27 16:48:44.367: E/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method aat.b
11-27 16:48:44.367: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 777 (Lcom/google/android/chimera/Activity;) in Laat;
11-27 16:48:44.367: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x016f
11-27 16:48:44.414: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1333 (common_full_open_on_phone) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$drawable;
11-27 16:48:44.414: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0060
11-27 16:48:44.414: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lig;.common_google_play_services_notification_ticker
11-27 16:48:44.414: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6317 (common_google_play_services_notification_ticker) in Lig;
11-27 16:48:44.414: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0092
11-27 16:48:44.421: I/PackageManager(484): findPreferredActivity: No PreferredActivities set
11-27 16:48:44.429: D/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lig;.common_open_on_phone
11-27 16:48:44.429: I/dalvikvm(4984): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x18b5 at 0x62 in Llf;.a
11-27 16:48:44.492: I/dalvikvm(4984): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig.zzb
11-27 16:48:44.492: W/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1602: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
11-27 16:48:44.492: D/dalvikvm(4984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0031
11-27 16:48:44.523: I/Ads(4984): Starting ad request.
11-27 16:48:44.531: I/Ads(4984): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("A3CEC832E11F54A868D9A89DDE949ED7") to get test ads on this device.
11-27 16:48:44.562: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1309K, 38% free 5088K/8088K, paused 5ms+18ms, total 72ms
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128): Failed to load module version after staging APKs
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at com.google.android.chimera.container.ConfigurationManager.getModuleVersion(:com.google.android.gms:564)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.ModuleProvider.query(:com.google.android.gms:1110)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
11-27 16:48:44.570: W/ModuleProvider(1128):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-27 16:48:44.585: W/DynamiteModule(4984): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
11-27 16:48:44.585: I/DynamiteModule(4984): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
11-27 16:48:44.585: W/DynamiteModule(4984): Failed to load module via fast routeaje: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
11-27 16:48:44.601: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(4984): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
11-27 16:48:44.671: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
11-27 16:48:44.671: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
11-27 16:48:44.671: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
11-27 16:48:44.671: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
11-27 16:48:44.687: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
11-27 16:48:44.695: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
11-27 16:48:44.695: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
11-27 16:48:44.718: V/ADS(4984): Showing ads, ontop
11-27 16:48:44.749: I/dalvikvm(4984): Total arena pages for JIT: 18
11-27 16:48:44.828: I/Finsky(1223): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.do.onTrimMemory(17): Memory trim requested to level 20
11-27 16:48:44.828: W/Finsky(1223): [1] com.google.android.finsky.application.FinskyAppImpl.F(1569): No account configured on this device.
11-27 16:48:44.906: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 36% free 5180K/8088K, paused 6ms+7ms, total 53ms
11-27 16:48:44.937: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(4984): Failed to load module version after staging: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
11-27 16:48:44.937: W/DynamiteModule(4984): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
11-27 16:48:44.937: I/DynamiteModule(4984): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
11-27 16:48:44.937: E/AppStreamingFragment(4984): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
11-27 16:48:45.117: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:45.359: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:45.835: I/PackageManager(484): findPreferredActivity: No PreferredActivities set
11-27 16:48:45.929: W/ContentTaskController(957): Invalid newTask was provided to startTracking.
11-27 16:48:45.960: D/WebView(1128): loadUrlImpl: called
11-27 16:48:45.960: D/webcore(1128):  CORE loadUrl: called
11-27 16:48:45.968: D/webkit(1128): Firewall not null
11-27 16:48:45.968: D/webkit(1128): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 16:48:46.249: I/Ads(1128): Received log message: <Google:HTML> You are using version 8.3 of the Google Play services Ads SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. See  for instructions on how to get the latest version of Google Play services.
11-27 16:48:46.289: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:46.359: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:46.773: I/Ads(4984): Trying mediation network: 
11-27 16:48:46.773: I/Ads(4984): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
11-27 16:48:46.781: W/Ads(4984): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter. com.google.DummyAdapter
11-27 16:48:46.781: I/Ads(4984): No fill from any mediation ad networks.
11-27 16:48:46.781: I/Ads(4984): Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.
11-27 16:48:46.781: W/Ads(4984): Failed to load ad: 3
11-27 16:48:46.781: D/setAdListener(4984): onAdFailedToLoad: No fill
11-27 16:48:46.859: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 408K, 37% free 5172K/8088K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 50ms
11-27 16:48:47.281: D/dalvikvm(4984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 35% free 5289K/8088K, paused 7ms+7ms, total 51ms
11-27 16:48:47.374: I/PlayCommon(1223): [127] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(853): Preparing logs for uploading
11-27 16:48:47.406: W/PlayCommon(1223): [127] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1194): No account for auth token provided
11-27 16:48:47.414: I/PlayCommon(1223): [127] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(993): Connecting to server: https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true
11-27 16:48:47.460: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:47.749: D/dalvikvm(1223): GC_CONCURRENT freed 897K, 38% free 5114K/8232K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 45ms
11-27 16:48:48.632: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:49.085: I/PlayCommon(1223): [127] com.google.android.play.a.g.a(1068): Successfully uploaded logs.
11-27 16:48:49.804: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:50.374: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(719): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
11-27 16:48:50.976: D/SensorService(484):   0.3 -1.0 9.8
11-27 16:48:51.109: I/Monitor(484): SIOP:: Current AP = 0, CP = 0
```

Comment: If I compile with greater versions than 8.3 of Google Services I get these errors: "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'." and "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'."